# Convert nested JSON with no first level keys into Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I've got the following jsonFile example that I'm trying to convert to a dataframe. I've looked through many examples on SO but all of them have a first level key in their json data. My data only has the value as the first level.

```html
[
  {
    "product1": [
      {
        "start": 8,
        "end": 9,
        "part_number": "150-3333-900",
        "description": "Description for 150-3333-900"
      },
      {
        "start": 8,
        "end": 9,
        "part_number": "150-4444-900",
        "description": "Description for 150-4444-900"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "product2": [
      {
        "start": 10,
        "end": 11,
        "part_number": "140-2222-800",
        "description": "Description for 140-2222-800"
      },
      {
        "start": 10,
        "end": 11,
        "part_number": "140-5555-800",
        "description": "Description for 140-5555-800"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I've tried the following and got a NotImplementedError. I thought this should work since I'm passing in a list of dictionaries.

```
import pandas as pd
import json

df = pd.json_normalize(jsonFile)
```

I tried the following and got some output but not in the format I'm looking for.

```
with open(jsonFile) as f:
    data = json.load(f)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
display(df)
```

And I get this:

[image]

I also get the same output using this line of code:

```
df = pd.read_json(jsonFile, orient='records')
display(df)
```

What I'm looking for is this:

[image]

Can someone point me in the right direction? I tried transposing the output that I got above so my column headers would be the beginning of each row but I couldn't get that to work either. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your desired result by iterating the dicts in your list, applying `json_normalize` to each one and appending the key as the product name:

```py
products = json.load(jsonFile)
dfs = []
for product in products:
    for name, details in product.items():
        dfs.append(pd.json_normalize(details).assign(pcr=name))

out = pd.concat(dfs).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output for your sample data:

```
   start  end   part_number                   description       pcr
0      8    9  150-3333-900  Description for 150-3333-900  product1
1      8    9  150-4444-900  Description for 150-4444-900  product1
2     10   11  140-2222-800  Description for 140-2222-800  product2
3     10   11  140-5555-800  Description for 140-5555-800  product2
```

Comment: Thank you @Nick. This solves my problem and I understand what it's doing.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible option :

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{"pcr": k, **p} for d in data for k, v in d.items() for p in v])
```

Output :

```
print(df)

        pcr  start  end   part_number                   description
0  product1      8    9  150-3333-900  Description for 150-3333-900
1  product1      8    9  150-4444-900  Description for 150-4444-900
2  product2     10   11  140-2222-800  Description for 140-2222-800
3  product2     10   11  140-5555-800  Description for 140-5555-800
```

Comment: Thank you @Timeless. This also solves my problem and is very efficient with the list comprehension. I need to dive in a little deeper to fully understand it but both solutions are acceptable to me.